# Why my home PC wallpaper updates to my office wallpaper

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10

In my office, they have some server policy that changes the wallpaper every month. I can't change my wallpaper there.

The problem is that my home PC and laptop also get updated, and I dont know why. And even when I change the wallpaper, it is reverted back to the office one. The only relation that I can think of is that my computers are linked to my Hotmail or Gmail account.

All three PCs are running Windows 10.

**What should I do to prevent my home PC and laptop from getting their wallpapers updated?**

[image: desktop wallpaper]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're logged into the same microsoft account in both ... you shouldn't. Always a good idea to separate business and pleasure. Windows 10 syncs wallpaper and theme settings between PCs if you're logged in the same account.

As per the comments, while its handy, this risks leaking work information home and vice versa and is typically a terrible idea. Best practice here would be to have dedicated accounts on/with AD - and considering they're pushing wallpapers anyway, there's no reason this shouldn't be in place.

Otherwise go to the sync your settings app (should turn up if you type in settings)  and turn off theme syncing. Assuming your workplace pushes it over GPO, it would be easier to turn it off there

[image]

Set that setting to off and you should no longer sync wallpaper and other things.

Comment: There are potentially massive security concerns with this. I really can not fathom why anyone would think this would be a good feature to implement unless they were interested in harvesting private data... All the more reason to steer clear of Windows 10.

Comment: Its pretty handy if you have more than one PC and you want semi consistent settings. And its trivial to turn off or to use a local account or domain account.

Comment: "If you're logged into a microsoft account ... you shouldn't." FIFY

Comment: @James The data can be encrypted, you know, right? As someone who has had multiple computers at multiple locations, getting the exact same setup (ex. same background, files, settings) across all the devices was a large convenience. It also made the new computer setup or reinstall much easier since I didn't need to bother with any of this.

Comment: Gee MS didn't think very hard at all. There's no business allowing this to propagate GPO settings.

Comment: @Joshua That isn't MS fault. There is an easy setting to block private IDs from being logged into on Domain computers, and the business has apparently not set this. If you're a small business where people use their work computers for personal stuff and personal stuff for work this setting isn't as big an issue.

Comment: @music2myear: Bah! GPO should not traverse the MS account. This is a security violation.

Comment: GPO Doesn't traverse the account, but it touches elements the MS account also touches. GPO has always been able to set desktop backgrounds. MS accounts have been able to do this since Windows 8.

Comment: @Lan Is it encrypted by default? Who has the keys? What intermediate storage does MS do? Why not just offer the ability to export a settings file?

Comment: @James It is encrypted in transit always through SSL and they are encrypted at rest. By default they have the keys but you ask for Microsoft to keep the key, keep it yourself, or both (you can regenerate the keys). These are settings for what colour you like your windows or backgrounds....I'm really not concerned about it. OP isn't since they posted a screenshot. Have you ever used four computers daily? This is a nice quality of life feature for multi-computer users; exporting and carrying around the settings on say a USB negates the benefit of seamlessly moving to a difference device.

Comment: The list in the picture includes more than window colours. Passwords, IE settings (browsing history), "Other Windows settings". I use multiple devices daily, and I prefer having a separation of environment and security of data. And lets not be naïve about this, QoL is not at the forefront of MS mind here - it is about getting data to sell/use for advertising purposes.